# Add Filter Based on Client Certificate Name (OpenVPN)

Tags: openvpn, filter

Can anyone show me how to filter (change bandwidth, delay, etc) of one or more users connecting to OpenVPN based on their Client Certificate Name?

Why I would like to use the Client Cert name is I could have 100's of users connecting to OpenVPN and I would like to individually limit the bandwidth of each client

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the directives `client-connect <cmd>` and `client-disconnect <cmd>`.

An environment variable `$common_name` is passed to the script specified at `<cmd>` and can be evaluated to use specific `tc` settings on that particular client as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$common_name" == "client1" ]; then
    downrate=100mbit
    uprate=100mbit
  elif [ "$common_name" == "client2" ]; then
    downrate=10mbit
    uprate=10mbit
  else
    downrate=10kbit
    uprate=10kbit
fi

tc qdisc add dev "$dev" root handle 1: htb
tc qdisc add dev "$dev" handle ffff: ingress

# Limit traffic from VPN server to client
tc class add dev "$dev" parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate "$downrate"
tc filter add dev "$dev" parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 \
  u32 match ip dst "$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip"/32 flowid 1:1

# Limit traffic from client to VPN server
tc filter add dev "$dev" parent ffff:0 protocol ip prio 1 \
  u32 match ip src "$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip"/32 \
  police rate "$uprate" burst 80k drop flowid :1
```

The following environment variables are relevant:

- `$common_name`: containing the client CN-name
- `$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip`: containing the client remote vpn IP
- `$dev`: containing the tun interface

A detailed setup can be found in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/780233/209089).